# List indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer, indices

I'm using a dictionary to compile data about stocks and such but when I come to reference the gtin code input by the user, i get the error 'List indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python'

This is the only section of code that causes this:

```
tempStockLvl = [num]['STOCK_LEVEL']  # This is the line the error references
tempStockLvl = int(tempStockLvl)
tempStockLvl = tempStockLvl - quantity
stock[num]['STOCK_LEVEL'] = tempStockLvl
```

Error:

`File "E:\Computer Science\CODE FINAL v2.py", line 206, in subtractQuant
    tempStockLvl = [num]['STOCK_LEVEL']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers :D

Comment: what is the value of that `num`?

Comment: It's an eight digit number, i.e. 12345670 (a GTIN code)

Comment: What do you expect from the line of code?

Comment: `[num]['STOCK_LEVEL']` - were you trying to index some sort of nested data structure? `something[num]['STOCK_LEVEL']`?

Comment: @user2357112 It's a dictionary, and in the dictionary you use the gtin code to find out what data matches the code

Comment: @AndrewLi i expected the stock level stored in the dictionary about that gtin code to be assigned to the new variable

Comment: "It's a dictionary" - whatever "it" is, you seem to have entirely forgotten to include it anywhere in this code.

Comment: @HeatherLara It's not a dictionary, it's a list...

Comment: Also, the code you posted is clearly not the same as the code the error message is coming from.

Comment: Same problem: the object is missing (probably just `stock`).

Comment: Try changing ```tempStockLvl = [num]['STOCK_LEVEL']``` to ```tempStockLvl = stock[num]['STOCK_LEVEL']``` - what happens then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a List with num as the only element, so it's clear it can't be accessed by anything other than index [0].

```
>>> num = 123
>>> l = [num]
>>> l
[123]
>>> l[0]
123
>>> [123]['anything']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>>
```

---

Did you mean to write `tempStockLvl = stock[num]['STOCK_LEVEL']`?

Comment: It's not a list, it references a dictionary (or tries to)

Comment: @Heather Do you know about [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?